# Error on Experience Cloud filter during deploy (Account.Id on standard Chart component)

Tags: lightning-experience, deployment, experience-cloud, experience-builder-page, experience-bundle

We are trying to push our Experience Site (using ExperienceBundle with mdapi) and are getting this error with the standard component. Seems like there was a similar issue that affected changesets:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001Sp12QAC&title=we-couldn-t-validate-componentattributes-when-attempting-to-deploy-community-themes-via-change-set

**Our exact error:**

```
Error  src/experiences/Community1  Community1  We couldn't validate componentAttributes in Community1/views/home.json for component 7b96310c-dd29-41bc-91a1-7850d5b0f485. Error: attribute [filterName]: Account.Id is not a valid value.. Check your file and try again.
```

Anyone who has ran into this recently? Here is the JSON structure for the chart:

```
{
  "componentAttributes" : {
    "cacheAge" : 1440,
    "filterName" : "Account.Id",
    "reportId" : "00O03000000VR90",
    "showRefreshButton" : false,
    "showTitle" : false
  },
  "componentName" : "forceCommunity:reportChart",
  "id" : "7b96310c-dd29-41bc-91a1-7850d5b0f485",
  "renderPriority" : "NEUTRAL",
  "renditionMap" : { },
  "type" : "component"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReportIds` attribute varies between the environments.

Hence the only way to deploy this is by adding the relevant report to the environment first and then noting its ID and then in the `views/home.json` replacing it with the right report ID.

We know this is a hassle at this point and the team is aware and working on giving the environment an independent solution.

Comment: There is any update on this? Like the possibility to add the report name instead.

Comment: In product roadmap but nothing as of now. You can script up if you need to